# How to use the bool data type?

Tags: c

I have in my code the specificacions of the bool to return true or false but I don't figure how to printf depending if it is true or false.
I have some float prompted by the user and the bool to determine if it is true or false.
How can I use these both datas to printf depending?

```
bool valid_triangle(float x, float y, float z);
int main(void)
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    do
    {
        x = get_float("Enter a length: ");
    }
    while(x <= 0);
    do
    {
        y = get_float("Enter other length: ");
    }
    while(y <= 0);
    do
    {
        z = get_float("The last one: ");
    }
    while(z <= 0);
}
if(valid_triangle = 1)
{
    printf("It's a triangle");
}
bool valid_triangle(float x, float y, float z)
{
    if(x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if((x + y <= z) || (x + z <= y) || (y + z <= x))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried an if conditional with the bool but doesn`t compile.
[image: Image from the error]

Comment: Please don't post text as images, it makes it very hard to read for some people who might otherwise be able to help (like me).

Comment: You have `if(valid_triangle = 1)` outside any function.

Comment: Also don't forget how to *call* functions, just because they return a `bool` value doesn't mean you don't have to call the function the normal way. Also don't forget the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: Your code formatting is a mess and therefore you have mismatching braces everywhere. Fix the formatting and you'll notice the bugs.

Comment: Have you tried to learn what are functions in C++ and how to call these? For example cppreference is quite good site: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if(valid_triangle = 1)
```

tries to re-assign the `valid_triangle` function to the integer 1. That does not compile; the names of functions behave like constants and cannot be assigned to.

You need something like:

```
if (valid_triangle(x, y, z))
{
  printf("yay, got a valid triangle with sides %f, %f and %f!\n", x, y, z);
}
```

The above *calls* the `valid_triangle()` function, passing it the three values you collected from the user. If the return vale is non-zero (which `true` is), the `if` will execute its body, otherwise it will be skipped.

Note that I (strongly) advise against explicit comparisons against booleans, since the comparison operator itself simply results in a boolean value which makes it feel painfully recursive to me. I also don't think it's any clearer.

Comment: I did a code without booleans but the same specifications and is easier but I wanted to try it with the bool to learn more about functions. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your valid_triangle function expects 3 arguments x, y, z. You have to pass the values you take from user to the function.

```
if(valid_triangle(x, y, z) == true)
{
    printf("It's a triangle");
} else {
    printf("It's not a triangle");

}
```

Comment: The "== true" wasn't necessary. Thank you so much!

Comment: `== true` is not only unnecessary. It can also introduce bugs.

Answer (score 0):

As other questions have shown ways to correct the errors in your code, I'll try to answer your primary question:

```
    printf("%s a triangle\n", 
            valid_triangle(x, y, z) 
                ? "It's" 
                : "It is not");
```

can be a compact and efficient way to print your boolean result in a user
friendly way.  Also

```
    puts(valid_triangle(x, y, z)
            ? "It's a triangle"
            : "It is not a triangle");
```

is even more compact, and more efficient, as it avoids the parameter substitution that requires `printf(3)` to substitute the proper string
above.